# What's the proper SQL query to find a 'status change' before given date?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of logged 'status changes'.  I need to find the latest status change for a user, and if it was a) a certain 'type' of status change (`s.new_status_id`), and b) greater than 7 days old (`s.change_date`), then include it in the results.  My current query sometimes returns the second-to-latest status change for a given user, which I don't want -- I only want to evaluate the last one.

How can I modify this query so that it will only include a record if it is the most recent status change for that user?

#### Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (s.applicant_id) s.applicant_id, a.full_name, a.email_address, u.first_name, s.new_status_id, s.change_date, a.applied_class
        FROM automated_responses_statuschangelogs s
        INNER JOIN application_app a on (a.id = s.applicant_id)
        INNER JOIN accounts_siuser u on (s.person_who_modified_id = u.id)
        WHERE now() - s.change_date > interval '7' day
        AND s.new_status_id IN
            (SELECT current_status
             FROM application_status
             WHERE status_phase_id = 'In The Flow'
            )
        ORDER BY s.applicant_id, s.change_date DESC, s.new_status_id, s.person_who_modified_id;
```

Comment: Can you provide sample output in which `second-to-latest` records are included ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to filter one entry per applicant:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() over (partition by applicant_id 
                                   order by change_date desc) rn
        ,       *
        from    automated_responses_statuschangelogs
        ) as lc
join    application_app a 
on      a.id = lc.applicant_id
join    accounts_siuser u 
on      lc.person_who_modified_id = u.id
join    application_status stat
on      lc.new_status_id = stat.current_status
where   lc.rn = 1
        and stat.status_phase_id = 'In The Flow'
        and lc.change_date < now() - interval '7' day
```

Comment: Actually AFAIK `distinct on` is faster than `row_number()` and I don't know how your code will help OP to avoid to get `second-to-latest`

Comment: Yes, won't this still return all the results starting 7 days ago, and then give me the first one of those (potentially being a second-to-latest record)?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.  You can move the filter outside the subquery to only test the latest entry, see updated answer.

Comment: @Andomar: Great work!  I'm curious about the course mentioned in your profile.  Is [this course](https://www.coursera.org/course/db) the one your recommending?

Comment: PS: The equality operator on the last line is flipped, but other than that, this query nailed it!  (I couldn't make that edit, as it's less than 6 characters?)